# Do you really need a database service such as AWS or MongoDB, when using blockchain?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, blockchain

I had a very tough time understanding where I should use blockchain without databse services such as AWS or MongoDB, since in blockchain, nodes usually contain a duplicate data of the blockchain.

Comment: This probably comes down to the distinction between read-side and write-side. If you need to efficiently look up a piece of data it is sometimes nice to have a secondary "index" datastructure when the primary "store of record" is not conveniently arranged for your type of query.

Comment: 1. AWS is not a DB service. 2. If it's not clear to you where to use blockchain, maybe you just shouldn't use it.

Comment: a blockchain is not a storage application, it is a data structure which can be stored however you want, as a flat file, in a database, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Block-chain is a distributed database. Please do not use block chain just for using it until you have real use-case for it.. because for sure block-chain will not be as good in performance as MongoDB etc.

Having said that in any application ; there can be different type of data to be stored which is updated/accessed by different use-cases.. So, it is very very application specific.. I feel in most applications you should be using both databases to get better performance.

Comment: Well, it's distributed, but I wouldn't call it a database. Isn't it more of a "ledger"?

Comment: Yes you are are right.. But just for understanding of this question; it is a place to store data. and in our technology world that place is called a database..